# How to use Custom Activity (batch) in Azure Data Flow in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I do have a Python script which I want to use in Azure datafactory.

I have created a Azure Data Flow which reads parquets from the Storage Account.

I have a python script which reads parquet and transforms from the storage account.

**Current Pipeline:**

I have this in the dataflow in ADF:
[image]

And the Custom Activity in the Pipeline:
[image]

Expected Result:

Is there a way to use this Custom batch Activity in the Dataflow ?  because I have the Python script running as custom: to read parquet file and transforms the data, now How do I ingest data to the sink ( because sink is only in the Dataflow)

Case1: Either Read through Custom Activity and then use it in Dataflow for further Sort and Sink.

Case2: Use DataFlow source to Read file, Use custom for transformations and Dataflow for sink.

How do I make use of the Python script(pandas) in here, with the DataFlow features.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use custom activity in dataflow.

Comment: Okay. So in this scene I can't utilise the features of data flow with custom activity.

Comment: Is there a way to ingest the data to SQL or nosql db after this custom activity in the pipeline ?

Comment: Hey, Can you please provide your end to end flow dgm if possible? What is the source and sink and where which component are you using ? Based on that we can provide how to map it?

Based on what I can understand, you can have the custom activity initially to read the parquet and do transformations, post which you can add the final file back in blob. Then you can leverage Dataflow to read and do further aspects

Comment: Sure @Nandan , Let me edit my question, I'll include more details. 
basically I want to read and do transformations and ingest into SQL or Influx db, this is the flow. 
Since there are couple of transformations, I wanted to include Pandas python as custom Batch activity and then want to use DataFlow sink option and other Sort and Filter options as well. But looks like Custom can't be used in the Dataflow. 

Then, I tried custom activity and then copy activity to Ingest to SQL db, but again Copy activity is asking for a source dataset, here I can't add custom as source. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom activity is a separate activity and cannot be used within datasets or dataflows.
So what I would suggest you to use Azure blob storage as stage layer between custom activity and dataflow/Copy activity.

you can split the output of the custom activity into an Azure blob storage in the form of file and that file you can use as a source within your copy activity or dataflow activity.

Comment: I get it, Thank you for this idea.  I'll give a try and let you know.

I'm ready to eliminate the usage of Python script in Custom if I can achieve what I want from the DataFlow actually.

What I want: Firstly, I would like to find the difference between last value and first value of the 30min sampling window, and secondly, also retain the row value of that considered/referenced row for the difference calculation. 

The first is high priority.